# linking ipopt against openblas

Tags: python, blas, openblas, ipopt

Currently, I am trying to build Ipopt linking against openblas. I downloaded the openblas source and did `make` in the parent directory.

The `configure` script of Ipopt has several options to link against blas:

I tried `./configure --with-blas="-L/home/moritz/build/CoinIpopt_test/ThirdParty/OpenBLAS-0.2.14/libopenblas.so"`

but I do get the error

`checking whether user supplied BLASLIB="-L/home/moritz/build/CoinIpopt_test/ThirdParty/OpenBLAS-0.2.14/libopenblas.so" works... no
configure: error: user supplied BLAS library "-L/home/moritz/build/CoinIpopt_test/ThirdParty/OpenBLAS-0.2.14/libopenblas.so" does not work`

Any tips how to achieve what I want ? Finally, I would like to make a conda package. I do have installed openblas with anaconda. But I do get the same error message if I link against the installed `libopenblas.so`

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it work. I had to install openblas to a directory of my choice by

```
make install PREFIX=/home/....../
```

aferwards I compiled Ipopt using

```
./configure --with-blas-incdir="-I/home/.../openblas/include/" --with-blas-lib="-L/home/.../openblas/lib/"
```

Comment: How did you find that solution (source)?  Also, I purposely misspelled the path to my blas lib, and it didn't give me an error.

Comment: Uh, that is too long ago